# Counter of corollary updated both after theorems and lemmas

Tags: numbering, theorems

I have the following definitions:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
```

Now I want to define corollaries so that their counter is updated both after theorems and lemmas in the following way:

```
Theorem i
    Corollary i.1
    Corollary i.2
Lemma j
    Corollary j.1
    Corollary j.2
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do load the `amsthm` or the `ntheorem` package in your preamble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your code loads the `amsthm` or `ntheorem` package, I suggest you create *two* corollary-like environments: `corrt` and `corrl`, to be used for corollaries associated with theorems and lemmas, respectively.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage{ntheorem} % no "." after theorem numbers
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{corrt}{Corollary}[theorem]
\newtheorem{corrl}{Colollary}[lemma]

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{theorem} bla bla bla \end{theorem}
\begin{corrt} ble ble ble \end{corrt}
\begin{corrt} bli bli bli \end{corrt}

\medskip
\setcounter{lemma}{4}
\begin{lemma} blo blo blo \end{lemma}
\begin{corrl} blu blu blu \end{corrl}
\begin{corrl} bly bly bly \end{corrl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Mico, very good solution!